# How can I use "different from" here? - He shakes hands with blacks in a different way from he does with whites

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction

I was quite impressed when I saw Lebron shaking hands with people.

> 1. He shakes hands with blacks in a different way from he does with whites.
> 2. He shakes hands with blacks in different ways from he does with whites.

I know I can say like this:  "He shakes hands with blacks in the same way as he does with whites.". I think ***different from*** and ***the same as*** is kind of similar, and that's why I think #1 and #2 is possible to use, I'm not sure which one is right among ***a different way*** and ***different ways*** though. But, in that ***from*** is a preposition, I'm not sure it's right grammatically. So,

> 3. He shakes hands with blacks in a different way from the way he does with whites.

I think it is the best.

> 4. The way of him shaking hands with whites and blacks are different.

I think is it right as it is, without any worries

Comment: I think in 1 and 2 a 'how' is missing after 'from'.  Ought to be "...in a different way from *how* he does [it] with whites."  Just a feeling, I got nothing to prove it.

Comment: Other alternatives: He doesn't use the same handshake with whites that he uses with blacks. His handshake with whites is different from the one he uses with blacks. He shakes hands with whites differently than he does with blacks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Number 3 is correct, but long. Numbers 1 and 2 would be ok if you use "than" instead of "from". I would rephrase number 4 as "The way he shakes hands with whites and blacks is different." Here, you must use "is different" because "the way" is singular.

Answer (score 1):

Simple fix:

> He shakes hands with blacks in a different way from **how** he does with whites.

(HOW functions as a relative adverb, meaning "the way in which".